# Protobuf-net is spending excessive time in RuntimeTypeModel.TakeLock

Tags: c#, multithreading, protobuf-net

My issue is very similar to the one in this question: [protobuf-net concurrent performance issue in TakeLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396742/protobuf-net-concurrent-performance-issue-in-takelock). The difference is that in our case, we are using CompressedSerializer and Deserializing data. Following code is being called from 8 different threads (on 8 core CPU) each time we need to deserialize data.

```
var result = new ProtoCompressedSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, CustomStruct>>(...)
```

Here's the result from ANTS Performance Profiler:

[image: ANTS Performance Graph]

First node in the graph is our method which is calling Deserialize using the code above. The number on left in each box is time in seconds and on the right is Hit count. As you can see RunTimeTypeModel.TakeLock is taking a lot of time. In the linked question above, the suggestion was to precompile model. Is that possible for CompressedSerializer and it's Deserialize method? From performance perspective, is it better to create one serializer and share it among all threads? Is it thread-safe?

Comment: What is `ProtoCompressedSerializer` in this context? AFAIK, that is not a protobuf-net file; what is it doing? what does it encapsulate?

Comment: Sorry! just realized that ProtoCompressedSerializer is an internal class, implemented by another team, that first uncompresses the data buffer being passed to it and then passes the uncompressed buffer to ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<T>() as a memory stream. Still the issue seems to be in TakeLock.

Comment: I just found a "Timeout exception while inspecting metadata..." in our logs. Also, we're (de)serializing around ~200 datatypes and found this related bug as well http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=309

Comment: I've had a quick look at why it might be hitting this so aggressively… but have you tried calling PrepareSerializer during startup, and/or increasing the timeout?

Comment: I'm new to ProtoBuf and the documentation is somewhat lacking. Can you advise as to which of the following is better? What are the differences? and which one would avoid TakeLock altogether?
`RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Dictionary<string, CustomClass>)].CompileInPlace();`
vs
`ProtoBuf.Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Dictionary<string, CustomClass>>();`

Comment: Just tried profiling code after adding PrepareSerializer statement in constructor of main class. Still same result and performance issues in TakeLock. Isn't PrepareSerializer supposed to Not use TakeLock at all?

Comment: yup, well, mostly; I need to look into that; I don't suppose that there's any chance you would be able to share any of the model details with me (not necessarily on this forum). You could also try calling `.Compile()` and storing the fully compiled serializer; that bakes down to a different assembly that *doesn't include* that code.

Comment: @MarcGravell Please check your gmail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out several options and comparing their performance using Performance Profilers, I've come to the conclusion that `Dictionary<T,K>` is Not correctly supported by ProtoBuf-net and even initializing serializer beforehand won't help.

The solution is to wrap up the Dictionary into a new class as the only data member. This will not only improve performance several fold, we saw 3X improvement, but also virtually eliminate the use of TakeLock and associated timeout issues.

Example:

```
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract]
    [DataContract]
    public class ModelADict
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<string, ModelA> sub { get; set; }

        public ModelADict()
        {
            sub = new Dictionary<string, ModelA>();
        }
    }
```